# How to use token authentication while testing REST API

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework, token

I am trying to use test the API request by using tokens. I was able to extract the token but I struggle to find a way to use it.

This is how I get my token:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestUserAPI(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.created_user = UserFactory()
        User.objects.create_user(username='test', password='pass1234')

    def test_authentification(self):
        request = self.client.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/auth/',
                                  {
                                      "username": "test",
                                      "password": "pass1234"
                                  })

        TestUserAPI.token = request.data["token"]

        assert request.status_code == 200
```

and this is how I use it:

```
def test_profile(self):
    request = self.client.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/profile/',
                              TokenAuthentication = 'token {}'.format(TestUserAPI.token))

    assert request.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
```

It gives me 401 error. What is the correct way of using token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple and it's because of my inexperience with testing. The test_profile function doesn't register that a token has been asked in the test_authentification function. So I had to put both of them in the SetUp function for the token to be registered for every function in the class.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) correct header format is `Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b`

Answer (score 0):

According to official documentation the the token key should be Authentication and the token should be should be trailing Token and a white space.
In your code change token {} to  Token {}.
If the problem persists try to print request headers in you view by printing request.META to check the key.